# traversing a tree with node class being inherited by another class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, binary-search-tree

I am beginner programmer and completely new to Java. Everything works fine except for that I can't traverse this tree.

```
public class Node extends Utility {
    protected Node left;
    protected Node right;

    public Node() {this.left = null; this.right = null;}
    public Node go_left() {return this.left;}
    public Node go_right() {return this.right;}
    public void connect_left(Node connection) {this.left = connection;}
    public void connect_right(Node connection) {this.right = connection;}
}

public class Member extends Node{
    protected String Name;
    protected int id;

    public Member() {
        this.Name = null;
        this.id = 0;
    } 

    public Member(String Name, int id){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int get_member_id() {return id;}

    public String get_status() {return status;}
}

public class MemberList{
    protected Member m_root;
    public MemberList() {
        this.m_root = null;
    }

    public int validate_member_wrapper (int member_id){
        return validate_member(this.m_root, member_id);
    }

    protected int validate_member(Member root, int member_id) {
        if(root == null)
            return -1;
        if(root.get_member_id() == member_id) {
            if(root.get_status().compareToIgnoreCase("Active") == 0)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        if(root.get_member_id() < member_id)
            return validate_member(root.go_left(), member_id);
        else
            return validate_member(root.go_right(), member_id);

    }
}
```

I tried to run this code but an error says that I can't convert object type Node to Member.

```
validate_member(root.go_left(), member_id)
```

and

```
validate_member(root.go_left(), member_id)
```

don't allow me to pass in Node type object. However, from what I understand, Member inherited from Node, not allow to pass the Node? How do you fix this?

Edit1:
As someone pointed out in the comment, I tried to fix this by overriding the go_left() and go_right() functions in the Node class to the Member class but somehow it showed an error says that Node cannot be converted to Member.

Here are the changes

```
public class Node extends Utility {
    protected Node left;
    protected Node right;

    public Node() {this.left = null; this.right = null;}
    public Node go_left() {return this.left;}
    public Node go_right() {return this.right;}
}

public class Member extends Node{
    protected String Name;
    protected int id;

    public Member() {
        this.Name = null;
        this.id = 0;
    } 

    public Member(String Name, int id){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Member go_left() {return this.left;}
    public Member go_right() {return this.right;}

    public int get_member_id() {return id;}

    public String get_status() {return status;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Couldn't you pass Node type object into the functions since Member already inherited Node class?**

No. Its the other way around. If you declare method to be

```
protected int validate_member(Node root, int member_id)
```

then it would take Member as well as Node in input.

For ex. Consider another class

```
public class Leaf extends Node{
```

Leaf is not a Member so if you create object of leaf

```
Node leaf =new Leaf();
```

and try to send this Node to

```
protected int validate_member(Member root, int member_id)
```

it would be incorrect. So this not possible.

**How do you fix this problem?**

There are two ways.

1. Override the methods from Node and add the left and right variables to Member class **(Recommended)**

   ```
   public Node go_left() {return this.left;}
   public Node go_right() {return this.right;}
   ```

   to

   ```
   public Member go_left() {return this.left;}
   public Member go_right() {return this.right;}
   protected Member left,right;
   ```
2. Type cast while calling the method **(Unsafe)**

   ```
   validate_member((Member)root.go_left(), member_id)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I put the override code you suggested into the Member class but it still doesn't work either. Is there another safe way?

Comment: Did you change the return type in the overridden method to Member?

Comment: Yes, I tried to change Node to Member and it still didn't work.

Comment: Would you share the new code, along with the code where there is error?

Comment: The problem can be fixed by add two variables to Member class protected Member left, right; but I think you are using wrong design pattern. Could you explain what are you trying to accomplish? A BST in  made of Nodes which you have created using Node class .  So why did  you create a Member class? For standard implementation of BST refer this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/

Comment: Note that recommended way 1 won't work correctly by itself: `Member left,right` only hide the inherited `Node left,right` fields, code in `connect_left/right` (e.g.) will still be accessing those. And if you override those, you'll need a cast again.

Comment: Yes, and that would result in Member class overriding all methods of Node class as well as hiding all the variables of Node class. So I asked him what was the reason he create such a pattern as its only redundancy and no use of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

> because Member inherited Node, couldn't you pass Node type object into the functions since Member already inherited Node class

No, it's the opposite: you can pass a `Member` into a method with `Node` parameter.

Think of it this way: you call `root.get_member_id()`, but if `root` is just a `Node` and not a `Member`, it doesn't have this method.